# Python - Split crontab entry to 6 fields

Tags: python, split, cron

I would like to know how to split a crontab line into 6 variables like the following. Maybe with split() or other string functions.

```
Input:
0 5 * * * Command1 arg1 arg2;Command2 arg1 arg2;...

Output:
Var1 = 0
Var2 = 5 
Var3 = * 
Var4 = *
Vat5 = Command1 arg1 arg 2;Command 2 arg1 arg2...
```

Thanks

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: Robert, I know that this is not a code writing service (Although my question did like I am asking for code while I am not). s.split(None, 5) was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) has an optional 2nd argument to limit the number of returned values:

```
In [11]: s='0 5 * * * Command1 arg1 arg2;Command2 arg1 arg2;...'

In [12]: s.split(None, 5)
Out[12]: ['0', '5', '*', '*', '*', 'Command1 arg1 arg2;Command2 arg1 arg2;...']
```

Complete sample program:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    parts = line.split(None, 5)
    print('Input:')
    print(line)
    print('Output:')
    print('\n'.join('Var{} = {}'.format(i, v) for i,v in enumerate(parts)))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! exactly what I needed.

Comment: @user6901896 - don't forget to "accept" this as an answer, since you said ti worked, in order to help the community.